# Export an elliptic curve key from iOS to work with OpenSSL

Tags: ios, swift, security

I have a private/public key pair generated and stored inside Secure Enclave.

It is 256-bit elliptic curve key. (The only key type that can be stored in Secure Enclave).

I use `SecKeyCreateWithData` and `SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation` to import/export the public key between iOS devices, and it works.

However, the exported key doesn't seem to work with OpenSSL. 
Because it always show `'unable to load Key'` on this command.

```
openssl ec -pubin -in public_key_file -text
```

---

What's the way to export the key ? So I can use it with OpenSSL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To work with OpenSSL, you need `subject public key info (SPKI)`, either `DER` or `PEM` format.

SPKI contains essential information, for example, `key.type`, `key.parameters`, `key.value`.

`SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation` only returns raw key binary which is only `key.value` part.

You have to create SPKI from that `key.value`. The normal way to do this is to read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480, and encode ASN.1 structure to binary-encoded DER format.

---

But here is a shortcut.

Secure Enclave only supports one key type, 256-bit EC key `secp256r1` (equivalent to `prime256v1` in OpenSSL).

The SPKI in DER format is a binary encoded data, for example,

```
3059301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d03010703420004fad2e70b0f70f0bf80d7f7cbe8dd4237ca9e59357647e7a7cb90d71a71f6b57869069bcdd24272932c6bdd51895fe2180ea0748c737adecc1cefa3a02022164d
```

It always consist of two parts

1. fixed schema header `3059301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d030107034200`
2. raw key value `04.......`

You can create SPKI by combining these two parts.

`spki = fixed_schema_header + SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(...)`

---

```
func createSubjectPublicKeyInfo(rawPublicKeyData: Data) -> Data {
    let secp256r1Header = Data(bytes: [
        0x30, 0x59, 0x30, 0x13, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2a,
        0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07, 0x03, 0x42, 0x00
        ])
    return secp256r1Header + rawPublicKeyData
}

// Usage
let rawPublicKeyData = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(...)!
let publicKeyDER = createSubjectPublicKeyInfo(rawPublicKeyData: rawPublicKeyData)
write(publicKeyDER, to: "public_key.der")

// Test with OpenSSL
// openssl ec -pubin -in public_key.der -text -inform der
```

Comment: If I'm using OpenSSL generated Keys in iOS, do I need to perform a reverse of this process ? (which it seems like removing the first 52 characters from the key generated by OpenSSL)

Comment: Yes, SecKeyCreateWithData doesn't expect the fixed schema header so you'll need to perform the reverse. For example: CFDataDeleteBytes(mutableData, CFRangeMake(CFIndex(0), headerSize))

Comment: God sent you and your answer!

You just saved me hours of headache (and reading)