# Public key generated on iOS device invalid on Java server

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, java-security, commoncrypto

I have an issue with a `SecKeyRef` generated on iOS device - when trying to use it on Java server, the exception is thrown:

> InvalidKeyException: EC domain parameters must be encoded in the algorithm identifier

here's the code snippet from the server code:

```
String key = ...
byte[] byteKey =  Base64.decode(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
return kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);
```

The exception is thrown by `kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);`

The key is created on iOS, using `SecKeyGeneratePair`

```
[keyPairAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeEC forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[keyPairAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:256] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];

// Set the private key dictionary
[privateKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
[privateKeyAttr setObject:self.privateTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];

// Set the public key dictionary
[publicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
[publicKeyAttr setObject:self.publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];

// Set attributes to top level dictionary
[keyPairAttr setObject:privateKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs];
[keyPairAttr setObject:publicKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPublicKeyAttrs];

// Generate key pair
OSStatus sanityCheck = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr, &publicKeyRef, &privateKeyRef);
```

The key pair is created successfully. I then extract key's bit data using following code

```
CFDataRef publicKeyBitsRef = NULL;
NSMutableDictionary *queryPublicKey = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// Set the public key query dictionary.
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[queryPublicKey setObject:self.publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeEC forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];

[queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

// Get the key bits.
OSStatus sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyBitsRef);
```

Then, I export the key using [CryptoExportImportManager](https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/CryptoExportImportManager)

```
NSData *publicKeyIDERData = [manager exportPublicKeyToDER:keyBits keyType:(__bridge NSString*)kSecAttrKeyTypeEC keySize:256];
NSString *derKeyString = [publicKeyIDERData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45188232/1921348), the DER header contains info about key type and parameters and for `secp256r1` key it's equivalent of following data

```
[
    0x30, 0x59, 0x30, 0x13, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2a, 0x86, 
    0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2a,
    0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07, 0x03, 
    0x42, 0x00
]
```

Which is indeed added to key header on export.

`derKeyString` is then sent to backend and processed using Java code mentioned above. However, the exception is thrown.

The same backend processes also the key created on Android device using following code

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, "AndroidKeyStore");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(
                new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true).build());
        keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

The Android key works just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Have I forgotten about something while creating keys with `SecKeyGeneratePair` or exporting the public key?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Faced with the same problem.

Comment: @Joao posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, although I'm not sure why.

What I did is I ditched CryptoExportImportManager library and I'm manually creating key data, like so:

```
unsigned char _encodedECOID[] = {
    0x30, 0x59, 0x30, 0x13, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2a, 0x86,
    0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2a,
    0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07, 0x03,
    0x42, 0x00
};

NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData new];
[data appendBytes:_encodedECOID length:sizeof(_encodedECOID)];
[data appendData:keyBits]; // keyBits is od NSData type
```

Now the Java server properly creates public key from my string (base64 encoded from `data`).

However, having looked at source code of CryptoExportImportManager, the way it creates the encoded string from my key bits looks like that (in Swift):

```
let curveOIDHeader: [UInt8] = [0x30, 0x59, 0x30, 0x13, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2A, 0x86, 
                               0x48, 0xCE, 0x3D, 0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2A,
                               0x86, 0x48, 0xCE, 0x3D, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07, 0x03, 
                               0x42, 0x00]
let curveOIDHeaderLen: Int = 26

var data = Data(bytes: curveOIDHeader, count: curveOIDHeaderLen)
data.append(rawPublicKeyBytes)
```

It basically does exactly the same thing. So where's the difference?

Now the only thing that comes to mind is the difference in how the header is stored - in my case it's an array of `unsigned char`, in library's case it's an array of `UInt8`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16138470/1921348%5C), `C` types `unsigned char` and `uint8_t` are not equivalent, they are only guaranteed to have the same length, but can differ in i.e. byte ordering.

Though that question had nothing to do with Swift's `UInt8` (but was tagged `C`, of which Objective-C is superset), the documentation of Swift's [UInt8 type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint8) says nothing about it's relation to `unsigned char` type, that would be the only reasonable explanation I can see.